# can display but cannot save enlarged image with Pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am new to Python (2.7), so thank you in advance for your patience.

While I can display an enlarged JPG image with Pillow I can't save it.  (The question here highlights the issue how Pillow saves JPG files and contrasts the display feature with the save feature.) I don't get any errors, but the size of the new JPG image is smaller than the original. Code snippet follows:

```
 import os
 from os import listdir
 from os.path import isfile,join

 import PIL
 from PIL import Image

 DIR = raw_input("Enter the directory name. Type end when finished\n")
 arr = os.listdir(DIR)

 for i in range(0,len(arr),2):
   filename = os.path.splitext(arr[i])[0]+.'.jpg'
   filename = os.path.join(DIR,filename)

   image = Image.open(filename)
   width,height = image.size
   image_new = image.resize((width*2, height*2))
   image_new.show()  # works fine

   filename = os.path.splitext(arr[i])[0]+'new'+'.jpg'
   filename = os.path.join(DIR,filename)
   image_new.save(filename)  # produces a smaller JPG file
```

Any suggestions greatly appreciated! .

Comment: Does reopening the jpg file show that it's smaller? Perhaps it's just the DPI that changed?

Comment: Minor thing: Does `os.path.splitext(arr[i])[0]+.'.jpg'` work alright? There's a dot right next to the plus sign.

Comment: Matt--Yes, it does show that it's smaller.

Comment: Damien--that was a typo when I was entering the code into the StackOverflow editor.

Comment: Answered here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/53278155/2836621

Comment: Mark, it sounds like he's talking about the dimensions of the image and not the file size.

Comment: @Peter Maybe OP will clarify if he means size of file in bytes has decreased, or image width and height have decreased.

Comment: Peter, Mark--yes, I am talking about the image dimensions.  But both the size of the file in bytes and the image dimensions have decreased.

Comment: Please show how you deduce the image dimensions before and after and what they are.

Comment: I just gave it a quick test with a JPG and PNG image (trimmed down the code a little) and both did actually work alright for me

Comment: Mark: correction, the new image showed enlarged dimensions with print(image_new.size).  But the size in bytes was smaller.

Comment: Peter, can you share the code snippet that worked for you?

Comment: I unfortunately can't access pastebin so I'll paste it here, basically it's the same as yours but with hardcoded image paths: `from PIL import Image; image = Image.open(BASE_IMAGE); width,height = image.size; image_new = image.resize((width*2, height*2)); image_new.show(); image_new.save(OUTPUT_IMAGE)`. I'm checking the image dimensions with "right click > properties > details" on the images btw.

Comment: Problem solved!  Many thanks to all who answered.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Mark Setchell answered the question here and at stackoverflow.com/a/53278155/2836621. He gives an example of the use of the quality option in Pillow's size method (Image module), which affects the size of the image. See part of his answer below:

```
If you wish to retain more quality, you can specify a different value from 75 when saving. It is not recommended to go above 95 as it increases file size with no benefit:

  img.save('result.jpg', quality=90)
```

Peter validated the code sample provided here.

Thank you to all who contributed (Mark, Peter, Matt, Damian, sophros)

Nina Sweeney (beachmouse)
US Naval Research Laboratory

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)